# Order words by number of letters, then place words neatly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of words in javascript *similar* to this:

```
var words = ["mine", "minute", "mist", "mixed", "money", "monkey", "month",
             "moon", "morning", "mother", "motion", "mountain", "mouth", "move",
             "much", "muscle", "music", "nail", "name", "narrow", "nation",
             "natural", "near", "necessary", "neck", "need", "needle", "nerve",
             "net", "new", "news", "night"];
```

The words can be 1-25? letters long.

I have a `div id="words"`, with a set width of 700px (but I might change it from this).

Using css/javascript/jquery, how can I make it:

- Order the words by number of letters
- Place the words inside the div tag, left to right, but so that there are no gaps at the right edge of the words div, and there is even spacing between words on a line.
- Each word should have a border around it and a background.

Like this:

```
|reallylongwordssdf     shorterwordfdf     dfsdfsdfsdf     sdfsdfsdf|
|sdfsdfsdf   sdffsdop   sdfjpogs   sdfsds   dfsdsd   dfsdsd   dfsdsd|
```

I really have no idea where to begin with this. Perhaps I could manage to write code to order the words by number of letters, but after that, I'd be stuck.

Edit: **I forgot to add, the words must be links.**

Comment: Are you using a fixed-width font to display these by any chance? Otherwise, the number of characters that can fit inside 700px varies depending on the characters.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: I'm not using a fixed width font. I don't really want to (unless there is no choice), because they don't look as good.

Comment: Am I missing something or can you just sort them longest->shortest, dump them in the div, then set the text-align to justify?

Comment: @Brad Christie: I tried doing it with just CSS, and I couldn't get it working. I think I did try text-align:justify. Maybe I was doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6nLUU/4/

Summarized:

- Use simple JS sorting to sort the items; I've included a little library I wrote for making it easier to sort by arbitrary key(s).
- Use `text-align:justify` for the container to get the items to stick to the right edge.
- Include a massive empty element at the end of the list to wrap to the next line, so that the real last line is justified.
- Use CSS for the backgrounds and borders.

Comment: @Phrogz: Thought about an empty wrap element, but don't like the hack. Kudos to being 1st though. ;-) Puts the pressure on me to get something workable.

Comment: @BradChristie It is a bit hackish; I take a modicum of solace in using a somewhat-semantically-appropriate element (`<hr>`). (Not that this really matters much for JS-generated content.) I wish CSS had a `text-align:full-justify` similar to MS Word.

Comment: @Phrogz: This looks very close. However, it needs to sort the words to have the longest first instead of the shortest. Also, would it be possible to have 2px margin to separate lines? :)

Comment: @Phrogz: From what I'm reading, CSS3 has this functionality coming out: `text-align-last: justify;` and `text-justify: distribute;`

Comment: @bmaster: add `line-height: 2em;` to his `#words a` and just use `words.sort(function(x,y){return (x.length<y.length?1:(x.length>y.length?-1:0));});` instead of his beast. ;-)

Comment: @bmaster I've updated the link and demo to reverse the word order and use explicit `px` font size to get an exact pixel separation between lines (ugh). My seasoned opinion: you are going to wish you hadn't chosen specific pixel offset when you start dealing with various screen dpi and users with different zoom levels.

Comment: @BradChristie [citation needed] (desired) for CSS3 justification. :) And, shorter: `words.sort(function(x,y){ x=x.length; y=y.length; return x<y?-1:x>y?1:0; });` :D

Comment: @Phrogz: as requested, [text-align-last](http://www.css3.com/css-text-align-last/) and [text-justify](http://www.css3.com/css-text-justify/); Also, damn you for your shorter short-hand. :shaking fist: ;-) And I gave up trying, kudos to your solution. +1 internets to you sir.

Comment: @BradChristie Thanks for the links. And if you stay up 10 more minutes, you'll be awake 10 more minutes than I and win many more Internets, I predict. :)

Comment: After merging your comments into the jsfiddle, this is the final result which I'm 100% happy with: http://jsfiddle.net/6nLUU/13/ Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @bmaster: no problem. -- @Phrogz: You were wrong, U lose internets when i stay on longer, heh.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .xstyle{display:block; float:left; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px; border:1px solid black;}
    .spacer{display:block; float:left;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="words" style="width:700px;height:300px;border:1px solid red">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var words = ["mine", "minute", "mist", "mixed", "money", "monkey", "month",
                 "moon", "morning", "mother", "motion", "mountain", "mouth", "move",
                 "much", "muscle", "music", "nail", "name", "narrow", "nation",
                 "natural", "near", "necessary", "neck", "need", "needle", "nerve",
                 "net", "new", "news", "night", "big big big big big big big big big word"];

        (
            function fillWords() {
                words.sort
                (
                    function(a, b) {
                        return b.length - a.length;
                    }
                );

                if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
                    Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback, thisObj) {
                        if (typeof (callback) == 'function') {
                            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
                                callback.call(thisObj, this[i], i, this);
                        }
                    };

                if (!Array.prototype.some)
                    Array.prototype.some = function(callback, thisObj) {
                        if (typeof (callback) == 'function') {
                            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
                                if (callback.call(thisObj, this[i], i, this))
                                return this[i];
                        }
                    };


                var totalWidth = 0;
                var firstIndex = 0;
                var wBox = document.getElementById("words");
                var objList = [];

                function fillSpaces(count) {
                    var space = 700 - totalWidth;
                    var eachSpace = Math.ceil(space / count) + 1;

                    objList.some
                    (
                        function(sobj, i) {
                            if (i > 0) {
                                var spacer = document.createElement("div");
                                if (totalWidth + eachSpace > 700)
                                    eachSpace = 700 - totalWidth;
                                spacer.className = "spacer";
                                spacer.style.width = eachSpace + "px";
                                spacer.style.height = sobj.offsetHeight + "px";
                                wBox.insertBefore(spacer, sobj);
                                totalWidth += eachSpace;
                            }

                            return totalWidth >= 700;
                        }
                    );

                    if (totalWidth < 700) {
                        var spacer = document.createElement("span");
                        spacer.className = "spacer";
                        spacer.style.width = (700 - totalWidth) + "px";
                        wBox.insertBefore(spacer, objList[objList.length - 1]);
                    }
                }


                words.forEach
                (
                    function(item, index) {
                        var obj = document.createElement("a");
                        obj.href = "#";
                        obj.className = "xstyle";
                        obj.innerHTML = item;
                        wBox.appendChild(obj);
                        var ow = obj.offsetWidth;
                        totalWidth += ow;
                        if (totalWidth >= 700) {
                            totalWidth -= ow;

                            fillSpaces(index - firstIndex);

                            objList = [obj];
                            totalWidth = ow;
                            firstIndex = index;
                        } else {
                            objList.push(obj);
                        }
                    }
                );

                fillSpaces(words.length - firstIndex - 1);
            }
        )();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 vote for effort, however there a few things wrong with this. The first is that I can use jquery, so your solution uses a lot more code than a jquery solution does. Also, the spacing between words seems to be different sometimes.

Comment: It would appear that this code is assuming a monospace'd font (though without specifying it in the CSS).

Answer (score 0):

This answers part of your question.

> Place the words inside the div tag, left to right, but so that there are no gaps at the right edge of the words div, and there is even spacing between words on a line.
>
> Each word should have a border around it and a background.

In order to do this, I would wrap each word in a `<span>`. I would then set the class margins so that each span had the same amount of space between it and the following span. The span can be set with a slight left and right padding, a border and a background color.

**edit** If you want the words to be links, use an `<a>` tag in the same way as the span tag above